# MySQLdump leads to exceeding max connections. Skip-Quick as a solution?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Every night I do a full mysqldump of a 17G DB in MySQL 5.7.32. This worke for years, now I am doing some heavy load on inserts during the night which caused at exactly the backup time the connections to rise to max_connections which led to connections errors.

As the Server has enough RAM 64G (30G free), I increased max_connections from 150 to 300 in a first reaction.

However looking at the dump command I found the option -- [quick (also enabled by default)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) which tells me that it is exporting row by row.

```
--single-transaction --routines --quick --compact
```

I am thinking of changing this to `--skip-quick.` but dare to change this since I would need to check the restore again and this is very time consuming.

Looking at the connections over time I also noticed that there are some interruptions around that time period. So maybe connections stack up since there is a block during MySQLdump?

MySQL error log shows a large amount of the following error, although not at this time points but continuously throughout the day:

```
Aborted connection 63182018 to db: 'mydb' user: 'test' host: 'myhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

How would you approach this problem?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: mysqldump uses a single connection.

Comment: How come the connections spike from avg 20 to over 150 during the dump?

Comment: @danblack I added some graphs to better illustrate the problem. A backup starts at 1am, first files then MySQLdump. Which "might" fall into that time period 01:07 as LVM backup takes a few minutes. There is no backup at 0:18am as far as I am aware off.

Comment: Haven't used MySQL for long time, but you check some suggestions here. A similar question on SF https://serverfault.com/questions/398237/mysqldump-causes-too-many-connections

Comment: Are your tables innodb? Do your normal connection modify tables extensively?

Comment: Yes I use innodb. There are several remote connections writing to the db. I added some log file entry to the question.

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
F) complete MySQLTuner rept 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` takes only 1 connection.

There is 1 extra connection for `root`.  (Note the 151 vs 152.)  I hope you are not using `root` for your app; change that if you are.  Then allow mysqldump to be the only `root` process running when it is doing a dump.

Limite the number of connections requested -- by adjusting the web server (or whatever is doing connections).  Web servers tend to allow far more children than is efficient.

Disconnect (in the app) from MySQL when finished processing.

Lower `wait_timeout` -- this will lead to disconnecting idle threads or threads that are held unnecessarily long by a "connection pool".

Running `mysqldump` takes resources away from other queries; be sure to run it at off times.

Use the slowlog to find out what queries are the most impacted by the dump; then let's discuss improving them.

If you have an LVM snapshot, why bother with mysqldump?  LVM is so much faster and less invasive.